Modeling Yield Scenarios and Curve Shocks for Bonds
I would like to do the following:
Given a basket of bonds I want to generate different yield scenarios at a future time $T$ for the different bonds in my basket. I also want to see how I can shock the yield curve initially (using for example a parallel shift), and see how it impact my different yield scenarios at time $T$. In this way I want to be able to see how a shock of the yield curve affects the bond future price.
The first model I considered for this purpose is the HJM framework. However, I am uncertain about how to implement it in practice. Using the HJM framework, I would generate different forward rate scenarios for zero-coupon bonds and then price the bonds in my basket using these forward rate scenarios at time $T$, subsequently determining the yields.
Is this a correct method to achieve my objective? Should the forward rates be calibrated on the zero-coupon curve, or can they be directly calibrated on the bonds in my basket? Additionally, will this method allow me to incorporate initial yield curve shocks such as steepening or parallel shifts to observe their effects on my future scenarios?

Why not use something like PCA, and bond option volatility. In this way you can apportion implied vol based on the loadings variance to come up with some scenarios of the indep risk factors.

@user68819 can you detail what you have in mind? I don't really understand. I need to model the whole yield curve at maturity no? especiallly if i want to see how the bond future price reacts to PCA shocks

use a fitted curve to get the Principle components for the bonds (in the basket) -- then find the implied volatility with a similar delivery date (usually bond future options should give you a fair estimate, failing that approximate with swaptions) -- then apportion the variance to factor 1&2 (anything higher i think is overkill).

@user68819 Hmm interesting. So basically I have a zero-coupon curve. I do PCA on the difference between that zero coupon curve and the yields of the bonds in the basket. Then I select PC1 and PC2, and using the implied vol of $\sigma$ the bond future option I try to get the vol of PC1 and PC2 at maturity? To do so you look at how much variance PC1 explained in the past: $\lambda_1$(for ex:  $\lambda_1 = 0.9$ and then the implied vol of PC1 at maturity is: $\sqrt{\lambda_1} \sigma$? Then I take the forward zero-curve at the maturity of the bond future, and I add PC1 and PC2 to generate

different yields scenarios (assuming yields are log normally distributed).  But then how I can see how a steepening affects my bond future price? Like I shock my zero coupon curve initially, so my forward zero coupon curve changes and then my different yields scenarios change?

Why zero coupon ? Use a fitted yield curve. The PCs embed the steepening / flattening  information in them..

@user68819 Yes right! so then to see the impact of a steepening you shock intially the fitted curve by PC2 to see how it impacts the bond future price? and to calculate the bond future price you take the forward fitted curve and add PC1 and PC2 to generate the possible yields scenarios?

sorry - i think there are still some misconceptions:

PC1 by definition will contain some flattening/steepening which depend on the general direction of rates. PC2 will contain steepening/flattening, independent of the factor driving PC1 (or outright rate levels).
Why do you want to revert to forward fitted curves? you have the fitted curve to start with (in spot space) -- that along with these PC generated scenarios is enough to "price" your basket of deliverables.


@user68819 the problem is that the future price is: $\mathbb{E}[\min \frac{P}{C}]$ so in order to calculate this expectation I need to generate different yield scenarios at maturities, for each of these scenarios find the CTD, and then the future price is the probability weighted average of these CTD. That's why I need a way to generate these yield scenarios at the delivery date to price the future, normally you use term structure model but maybe using the PCs it works idk... Is this what you had in mind?

The CTD can be calculated today as the bond which minimizes the Fwd[i]/CF[i] - the Fwd can be inferred as of today for a certain delivery using the spot fitted curve.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
